# NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle where decimals are only shown when period is used on the keypad

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I am a new obj c programmer, and I haven't figured out what condition to switch for the following scenario:

That is to say, if user types "1", then the fee will be "$1", if user types "1" then "2", the fee will be "$12", if user types "1" "2" then "3", the fee will be "$123". The user will need to manually type in decimal if they want there to be any cents.

I am using UITextField as the input field. Part of my code:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    cell.input = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 6, cell.frame.size.width, 80)];
    cell.input.currencyNumberFormatter = numberFormatter;
```

Would I place the condition in the UITextField method:

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {}

Any hint you can provide would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the currency code. Set the min and max fractions

```
[numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
```

Comment: Seems that setMinimumFractionDigits set to 2 as max no matter what. I tried setting 4 and it prints the price as 0.00. Where I want it to be 0.0000